# What's the right way to set up prototype chain in JS

Tags: javascript, prototype

I am trying to set up a prototype chain in Js with the following code.

```
const personBaseObject = {
  
  firstName: null,
  lastName: null,
  
  introduceSelf() {
    console.log(`Hi, I am ${this.firstName} ${this.lastName}`);
  },
  
  setFullname(...params) {
    [this.firstName, this.lastName] = params;
  },
  
  setFirstName(param) {
    this.firstName = param;
  },
};

const parent = Object.create(personBaseObject);
parent.setFullname("jane", "doe");

const child = Object.create(parent);

// const child = {};

// Object.setPrototypeOf(child, parent);

// child.__proto__ = parent;

child.setFirstName("john");

child.introduceSelf();
```

I read that `child.__proto__ = parent` shouldn't be used but can't understand the reason. Is there any difference between `Object.setPrototypeOf(child, parent)` and `const child = Object.create(parent);`

Comment: Since ECMAScript 2015, all this has become easier with the `class extends` syntax. Why not use it?

Comment: See [Inheritance and the prototype chain](//developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Inheritance_and_the_prototype_chain).

Comment: *"...but can't understand the reason"*: it is explained on [mdn](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/proto). Is there anything in that explanation that is not clear?

Comment: I am trying to learn how prototype works under the hood. I didn't want to use function constructor and class syntax because I want to understand.

Answer (score 0):

You **should really** use the class based syntax. It's powerful synthetic sugar (and more nowadays) on top of the rather confusing syntax we had to use before it.

But since you asked, it is possible to setup a correct prototype chain, including a reasonable implementation of "super", without classes. That would however be like re-inventing the wheel since we have the class syntax.

But let's reinvent the wheel for fun:

1. You need to set the constructor property wisely to get the chain working. it is a bit counterintuitive since it will always 'lag' one behind what you might expect in the prototype chain - but this is how it is when using classes too - even found a mdn article about Object.create which tried to go against this, but then you kinda break the prototype chain.
2. You don't need (and shouldn't) use **proto** or Object.setPrototypeOf. The latter is really only a good/acceptable option when monkey patching things.
3. **_super** *is* kind of magical - it will return the 'parent constructor'  if called by its own and the prototype methods of the parent prototype if called with a method after_super.sayHi() - this is how we reach overridden methods.

**The wheel reinvented**

```
/* Reinventing the wheel */
const basePrototype = {
  get _super() {
    let obj = this, c = obj.constructor;
    while (obj.constructor === c) {
      obj = Object.getPrototypeOf(obj);
    }
    let func = obj.constructor.bind(this);
    return new Proxy(func, {
      get: (t, prop) => obj[prop].bind(this)
    });
  }
};

function _class(_extends, _constructor, methods) {
  let proto = _extends === 'base' ?
    basePrototype : _extends.prototype;
  _constructor.prototype = Object.create(proto);
  _constructor.prototype.constructor = _constructor;
  Object.assign(_constructor.prototype, methods);
  return _constructor;
}
/* Done reinventing the wheel */

const Person = _class('base', function Person(name) {
  this.name = name;
}, {
  sayHi() {
    return `Hi! I am ${this.name}!`;
  }
});

const Student = _class(Person, function Student(name, course) {
  this._super(name);
  this.course = course;
}, {
  sayHi() {
    return this._super.sayHi()
      + ` I study ${this.course}.`;
  }
});


let s = new Student('Anna', 'programming');
console.log(s);
console.log(s.sayHi()) // => 'Hi! I am Anna! I study programming.';
console.log(s instanceof Person) // => true
console.log(s instanceof Student) // => true;
```

Now imagine how much harder this was in the old days before we even had *Object.getPrototypeOf*, *Object.assign* or for that matter *Proxy* to simulate the ***super** magic.*

*Let's look at the prototype chain, can you see what I mean with the constructor **'lagging 1 behind'** ? The Person prototype has the constructor Student and so on...*

[image: prototype-chain-wheel-reinvented]

But you shouldn't reinvent the wheel, just use class based syntax

**Class based syntax**

```
class Person {
  constructor(name) {
    this.name = name;
  }
  sayHi() {
    return `Hi! I am ${this.name}!`;
  }
}

class Student extends Person {
  constructor(name, course) {
    super(name);
    this.course = course;
  }
  sayHi() {
    return super.sayHi()
      + ` I study ${this.course}.`;
  }
}

let s = new Student('Anna', 'programming');
console.log(s);
console.log(s.sayHi()) // => 'Hi! I am Anna! I study programming.';
console.log(s instanceof Person) // => true
console.log(s instanceof Student) // => true;
```

*Let's look at the protoype chain, can you see that it behaves the same as when we reinvented the wheel earlier?*

[image: prototype chain class based]